# toggle open close target list

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

Scenario

Multiple UL lists on a page, and for each:
1: I want to have an open/close link
2: I want to display different quantities of each list

So far I can do (2) but when I try and do (1) my open/close opens all things on the page

Fiddle set up here: http://jsfiddle.net/topiman/WD9nf/2/

```
$('.show-more a').click(function() {
    $('.toggle-list').find('.toggle-items').slideToggle('fast');
    return false;
});
```

Ideally then:

a: Open link could change to 'Close' when opened

b: Each link opens only the relevan UL

c: The slide could be smoother

I've seen this kinda answered in other threads but usually the markup and trigger are in different places that I need them

Thanks in advance

.ben.

Comment: And le question is.....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You s hould find the `closest block-content` first then `find toggle-items`

```
 $('.show-more a').click(function() {
     $(this).closest('.block-content').find('.toggle-list .toggle-items')
            .slideToggle('fast');
     return false;
 });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar/WD9nf/12/)

Answer (score 2):

Use an instance of `this` to find the correct list, as for changing the text, a simple check in the callback of the toggle will do:

```
$('.show-more a').click(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    $(this).parent().prev(".toggle-list").slideToggle(function() {
        $(this).is(":visible") ? that.text("Close") : that.text("Open");
    });
    return false;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WD9nf/10/

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers :-) !! - Rohan I've tweaked yours to be able to include non-UL items

http://jsfiddle.net/topiman/WD9nf/17/

Can this be tweaked so that Open changes to Close etc

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers :-) !! - Rohan I've tweaked yours to be able to include non-UL items

http://jsfiddle.net/topiman/WD9nf/17/

Can this be tweaked so that Open changes to Close etc

Comment: @topiman -- Just add the ternary above into the callback, like `slideToggle('fast', function() {....});`